# Ant: Zip the contents of a directory, without the top-level directory itself

Tags: ant, zip

How can I use Ant to create zip containing all the files and nested directories inside some root directory, but exclude the top-level directory itself from the zip.

For example, say I have this file structure:

```
/foo
    splat.js
    /bar
        wheee.css
```

I want the zip to contain splat, and wheee inside /bar, but I **don't** want all that to be contained inside a 'foo' directory. In other words, unzipping this into /honk should ***not*** create a foo directory; splat and bar should end up at the root of /honk.

I'm currently using this (extraneous details removed):

```
<zip destfile="${zipfile}" basedir="" includes="${distRoot}/**/*.*" />
```

What kind of fileset select can replace that 'includes' spec to achieve this?

Comment: does a nested `<fileset dir="foo" includes="**/*" />` instead of the includes tag help? Or `basedir="foo" includes="**/*"`

Comment: +1 for mihi's comment, and see also: http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/zip.html -- it describes how to use fileset as nested elements in zip task.

Comment: Thanks guys, this does exactly what I need I think, will check more thoroughly when I have time: `<zip destfile="${zipfile}" basedir="${distRoot}" includes="**/*" />`. @mihi, if you make that an answer, I'll mark it correct.

Comment: Related with a nice solution: http://stackoverflow.com/q/22759314/435605

Answer (score 2):

It's not dynamic, but using the fullpath attribute allows you to define the path struture of the zip file. See ant documentation: http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/zipfileset.html

```
<zip destfile="YourZipName.zip">
    <zipfileset fullpath="splat.js" dir="foo" includes="splat.js"/>
    <zipfileset fullpath="bar/wheee.css" dir="foo/bar" includes="wheee.css"/>
</zip>
```

This may get you want you want dynamically. It should pull in everything in the foo dir then zip it up. It's just a few extra steps.

```
<mkdir dir="DirToBeZipped"/>
<copy todir="DirToBeZipped">
    <fileset dir="foo" includes="*"/>
</copy>
<zip destfile="YourZipName.zip" basedir="DirToBeZipped"/>
```