# How do I flatten the top level folder of a zip file with ant?

Tags: ant, zip, unzip, mapper

A lot of zip files have a root folder, how do I unpack the zip file and get rid of the root folder?

I know there is the `globmapper`:

```
<unzip dest="${dest.path}">
    <fileset dir="${source.path}">
        <include name="**/zipfile*.*.zip" />
    </fileset>
    <mapper>
        <globmapper from="rootFolder/*" to="*" />
    </mapper>
</unzip>
```

But what if I don't know the name of the root folder? Wildcards are not working e.g.

```
<globmapper from="root*Folder/*" to="*" />
```

Is there a way to use wildcards or a mapper/function that upacks without the root folder?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There's actually a separate mapper specifically made for this called cutdirsmapper.  Give this a try:

```
<unzip dest="${dest.path}">
    <fileset dir="${source.path}">
        <include name="**/zipfile*.*.zip" />
    </fileset>
    <cutdirsmapper dirs="1" />
</unzip>
```

Comment: exactly what I was looking for, thanks! don't know how I missed it on the ant mapper page...

Comment: `cutdirsmapper` is available since ant 1.8.2: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31837382/435605

Comment: awesome. Thank you

Comment: Official documentation link:  List of Ant Mappers which mentions `cutdirsmapper`:  https://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/mapper.html