# ant build - unzip doesnt support the nested "cutdirsmapper" element

Tags: git, ant, centos, unzip

I'm totally new to this and really need your help. i tried to build git distribution  using "ant" and got an error

> path~/build.xml: unzip doesn't support the nested "cutdirsmapper"
>   element

i have no idea how to fix this.
my system "Centos"  64bit

Comment: What do you mean by "git distribution"? The repo git itself (https://github.com/git/git)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<cutsdirmapper>` element was added in Ant 1.8.2 according to the [documentation](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/mapper.html), but you are presumably using an older version of Ant (try the `ant -version` command to see).  You can download/use a newer version of Ant, which is probably your easiest solution if you're not familiar with Ant scripting, or you can change the build script to use a different mapper.  For example, the `<flatten>`, `<glob>`, or `<regexpmapper>` might do what you want.

Comment: yep. my version was 1.7